# How to customize listview using baseadapter

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter, baseadapter

I wanna create a customized `ListView` like this:

[image: TextView+ImageView in ListView]

I think that I have to use `BaseAdapter` but I have no idea about it.

Comment: check the tutorial in the link http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/

Answer (score 59, accepted):

main.xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >

    </ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

custom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="255dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Video1"
                    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                    android:textColor="#339966"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />
            </LinearLayout>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical" >

                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/detail"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="video1"
                    android:textColor="#606060" />
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

main.java:

```
package com.example.sample;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    ListView l1;
    String[] t1={"video1","video2"};
    String[] d1={"lesson1","lesson2"};
    int[] i1 ={R.drawable.ic_launcher,R.drawable.ic_launcher};


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        l1=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        l1.setAdapter(new dataListAdapter(t1,d1,i1));
    }

    class dataListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        String[] Title, Detail;
        int[] imge;

        dataListAdapter() {
            Title = null;
            Detail = null;
            imge=null;
        }

        public dataListAdapter(String[] text, String[] text1,int[] text3) {
            Title = text;
            Detail = text1;
            imge = text3;

        }

        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return Title.length;
        }

        public Object getItem(int arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return null;
        }

        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            View row;
            row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
            TextView title, detail;
            ImageView i1;
            title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
            detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
            i1=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);
            title.setText(Title[position]);
            detail.setText(Detail[position]);
            i1.setImageResource(imge[position]);

            return (row);
        }
    }
}
```

Try this.

Comment: i Use this code, but the following Exception was raised java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=10; index=10

Comment: You have to use ViewHolder for performance...check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469073/how-do-you-efficiently-load-bitmaps-from-drawable-folder-into-a-listview/19469076#19469076

Comment: @ShaktisinhJadeja the layout inflater comes from the activity class since the adapter was implemented inside of it. Try - LayoutInflater.from(context) if it's a stand alone class.

Answer (score 15):

```
public class ListElementAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    String[] data;
    Context context;
    LayoutInflater layoutInflater;


    public ListElementAdapter(String[] data, Context context) {
        super();
        this.data = data;
        this.context = context;
        layoutInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {

        return data.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {

        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {


        convertView= layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);

        TextView txt=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);

        txt.setText(data[position]);



        return convertView;
    }
}
```

Just call ListElementAdapter in your Main Activity and set Adapter to ListView.

Comment: how can I use it ? ListElementAdapter adapter = new ListElementAdapter(array, this); will not work as it extends BaseAdapter and BaseAdapter is an abstract class

Comment: As the answer is too old and ListView is deprecated in Android. I would suggest you - Use Recycler View instead. Thanks

Answer (score 7):

Create your own BaseAdapter class and use it as following.

```
 public class NotificationScreen extends Activity
{

@Override
protected void onCreate_Impl(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    setContentView(R.layout.notification_screen);

    ListView notificationList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.notification_list);
    NotiFicationListAdapter notiFicationListAdapter = new NotiFicationListAdapter();
    notificationList.setAdapter(notiFicationListAdapter);

    homeButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.home_button);

}

}
```

Make your own BaseAdapter class and its separate xml file.

```
public class NotiFicationListAdapter  extends BaseAdapter
{
private ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> data;
private LayoutInflater inflater=null;


public NotiFicationListAdapter(ArrayList data)
{
this.data=data;        
    inflater =(LayoutInflater)baseActivity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}



public int getCount() 
{
 return data.size();
}



public Object getItem(int position) 
{
 return position;
}



public long getItemId(int position) 
{
    return position;
}



public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) 
{
View vi=convertView;
    if(convertView==null)

    vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.notification_list_item, null);

    ImageView compleatImageView=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.complet_image);
    TextView name = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.game_name); // name
    TextView email_id = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.e_mail_id); // email ID
    TextView notification_message = (TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.notification_message); // notification message



    compleatImageView.setBackgroundResource(R.id.address_book);
    name.setText(data.getIndex(position));
    email_id.setText(data.getIndex(position));
    notification_message.setTextdata.getIndex(position));

    return vi;
}

  }
```

BaseAdapter xml file.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/inner_layout"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"
android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
android:layout_weight="4"
android:background="@drawable/list_view_frame"
android:gravity="center_vertical"
android:padding="5dp" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/game_name"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Game name"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="15dip"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:typeface="sans" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/e_mail_id"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/game_name"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dip"
    android:text="E-Mail Id"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10dip" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/notification_message"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/game_name"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/e_mail_id"
    android:paddingLeft="5dp"
    android:text="Notification message"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="10dip" />



<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/complet_image"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="30dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:src="@drawable/complete_tag"
    android:visibility="invisible" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Change it accordingly and use.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest using a custom Adapter, first create a Xml-file, for example `layout/customlistview.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:paddingRight="4dp" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="23sp"
        android:maxLines="1" />
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/subtitle"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/image" android:layout_below="@id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 
</RelativeLayout>
```

Assuming you have a custom class like this

```
public class CustomClass {

    private long id;
    private String title, subtitle, picture;

    public CustomClass () {
    }

    public CustomClass (long id, String title, String subtitle, String picture) {
        this.id = id;
        this.title= title;
        this.subtitle= subtitle;
        this.picture= picture;
    }
    //add getters and setters
}
```

And a `CustomAdapter.java` uses the xml-layout

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter {

private Context context;
private int resource;
private LayoutInflater inflater;

public CustomAdapter (Context context, List<CustomClass> values) { // or String[][] or whatever

    super(context, R.layout.customlistviewitem, values);

    this.context = context;
    this.resource = R.layout.customlistview;
    this.inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = (RelativeLayout) inflater.inflate(resource, null);

    CustomClass item = (CustomClass) getItem(position);

    TextView textviewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
    TextView textviewSubtitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.subtitle);
    ImageView imageview = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);

    //fill the textviews and imageview with the values
    textviewTitle = item.getTtile();
    textviewSubtitle = item.getSubtitle();

    if (item.getAfbeelding() != null) {
        int imageResource = context.getResources().getIdentifier("drawable/" + item.getImage(), null, context.getPackageName());
        Drawable image = context.getResources().getDrawable(imageResource);
    }
    imageview.setImageDrawable(image);

    return convertView;
    }
}
```

Did you manage to do it? Feel free to ask if you want more info on something :)

**EDIT**: Changed the adapter to suit a List instead of just a List

Comment: Excuse me; please explain that how can i use this class in my activity containing a listview named "lv" ,and what is purpose of "toerismelistviewitem" in this line: "super(context, R.layout.toerismelistviewitem, values);"

Comment: Hi there, just fill in the name of your Xml-file, so in your case it will be super(context, R.layout.lv, values)  - I forgot to rename it :)
and I just got a List<String> values but probably want your strings in a list with 2 dimensions because you have a title and subtitle, you can change it in whatever you want, remember that.

Comment: I used a List<CustomClass> instead of List <String> so it will give both Strings and an url for the image. See my edit, I hope it's clear now...

Answer (score 4):

```
private class ObjectAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

    private Context context;
    private List<Object>objects;

    public ObjectAdapter(Context context, List<Object> objects) {
        this.context = context;
        this.objects = objects;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return objects.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return objects.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;

        if(convertView==null){
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, parent, false);
            holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        }else{
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }

        holder.text.setText(getItem(position).toString()));
        return convertView;
    }

    class ViewHolder {
        TextView text;
    }
}
```

Comment: how can I use it ? 
ObjectAdapter adapter = new ObjectAdapter(this, objects); 
will not work as it extends BaseAdapter and BaseAdapter is an abstract class