# how do you efficiently load bitmaps from drawable folder into a ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview

How do you load images from `drawable` folder into a `ListView` in a way this happens fast and does not use large amounts of RAM?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

**NOTE: this post is deprecated, please use the [RecyclerView](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/layout/recyclerview) for creating lists**

---

I've been playing around with loading some (quite large) images stored in the `drawable` folder into a `ListView` and in this post I'd like to share the result I came to. Maybe (I hope so) this will save someone plenty of time. I've tested the code I'm posting on several Android 4+ devices and I can say that it runs pretty smoothly and the amount of RAM used stays relatively low. Some explanations go as following:

- we are extending the `BaseAdapter`
- images will be loaded in background using an `AsyncTask`
- as common for this kind of adapters, we'll be using an `ArrayList<>` parametrized with `Objects` of some custom class. In my app, this class is called **Weapon**
- we will scale the images depending on the screen size
- we will apply a font to the `TextView` in each List Row

Feel free to use this code for any purposes and modify it in any way. The only thing I'm asking for is *to test the code properly before claiming that something doesn't work*. It works, believe me.

If you have noticed any copy-paste-edit mistakes (since I removed some code that is irrelevant for this little tutorial), your feedback is welcome.

Before I post the code, here's a small state diagram demonstrating the logic of the `getView()` method:

[image]

The code for the `Adapter` class goes below, I've tried to explain everything you need in comments:

```
public class WeaponAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements View.OnClickListener {

private ArrayList<Weapon> items;
private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
private WeaponHolder weaponHolder;
private Weapon wp;
private Context c;
private Bitmap bmp;

/*--- a simple View Holder class ---*/
static class WeaponHolder {
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image, addFav;
    public AsyncImageSetter mImageLoader;

}

/*--- Context and all weapons of specified class are passed here ---*/

public WeaponAdapter(ArrayList<Weapon> items, Context c) {
    this.items = (ArrayList<Weapon>) items;
    inflater = LayoutInflater.from(c);
    this.c = c;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return items.size();

}

@Override
public Weapon getItem(int position) {
    return items.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    /*--- initialize our Weapon Object ---*/
    wp = items.get(position);

    if (convertView == null) {
        /*--- no View is available. Inflate our list item layout and init the Views we need ---*/
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_row, null);
        weaponHolder = new WeaponHolder();
        weaponHolder.text = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.tvCatText);
        weaponHolder.image = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgCatImage);
        weaponHolder.addFav = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.imgAddFav);
        convertView.setTag(weaponHolder);
    } else {
        weaponHolder = (WeaponHolder) convertView.getTag();
        /*--- if convertView is not null, cancel the current loading operation to 
         * improve performance and decrease RAM usage ---*/
        weaponHolder.mImageLoader.cancel();
    }
    /*--- load the image in background ---*/
    weaponHolder.mImageLoader = new AsyncImageSetter(c, weaponHolder.image,
            wp.getImage(), bmp, weaponHolder.text);
    weaponHolder.mImageLoader.execute();
    weaponHolder.text.setText(wp.getName());
    weaponHolder.addFav.setOnClickListener(this);
    return convertView;

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {


        // do any stuff here



}
   }
```

Here's our `AsyncTask` that will load and set the images in background.

**NOTE:** my Weapon class has a `getImage()` method which returns the resId of the `drawable` corresponding to a Weapon `Object`. You can modify this part in a way it works for you.

```
public class AsyncImageSetter extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

private ImageView img;
private int image_resId;
private Bitmap bmp;
private Context c;
private boolean cancel = false;
private int sampleSize;
private TextView txtGunName;
private Typeface font;


public AsyncImageSetter(Context c, ImageView img, int image_ResId,
        Bitmap bmp, TextView txtGunName) {

    this.img = img;
    this.image_resId = image_ResId;
    this.bmp = bmp;
    this.c = c;
    this.txtGunName = txtGunName;

}

public void cancel() {
    cancel = true;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    /*--- we hide the Views from the user until the content is ready. This will prevent
     * the user from seeing an image being "transformed" into the next one (as a result of
     * View recycling) on slow devices. 
     */
    img.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtGunName.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    font = Typeface.createFromAsset(c.getAssets(), "b_reg.otf");
    super.onPreExecute();
}

@Override
protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {

    if (!cancel) {
        try {
            return decodeAndScale(bmp);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap result) {

    img.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    try {
        img.setImageBitmap(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        /*--- show an error icon in case something went wrong ---*/
        img.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_warn);
    }

    txtGunName.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    txtGunName.setTypeface(font);
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}

private Bitmap decodeAndScale(Bitmap bmp) {

    final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inSampleSize = setSampleSize();

    return BitmapFactory.decodeResource(c.getResources(), image_resId,
            options);

}

private int setSampleSize() {

    // TODO add multiple screens check
/*--- modify this method to match your needs ---*/
    if (GetSettings.getScreenWidth((Activity) c) >= 320) {
        /*--- physical width >= 480px ---*/
        sampleSize = 2;
    }

    return sampleSize;
}}
```

You may have noticed that I use the `getScreenWidth()` method from the `GetSettings` class. Its code is quite simple and returns a dp value representing the device's screen width:

```
    public static int getScreenWidth(Activity a) {

    Display display = a.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    DisplayMetrics outMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    display.getMetrics(outMetrics);

    float density = a.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    float dpWidth = outMetrics.widthPixels / density;

    return (int) dpWidth;

}
```

Well, that's all and I hope this post did help someone. Cheers.

P.S. if you are definitely sure something doesn't work, most likely it was caused by your internal app structure that is different from the one I use. In this case, I recommend you to do following steps:

1. Ask a new question so you'll be able to add properly formatted code and LogCat output
2. Notify me by adding a comment to my post. I will be glad to help you figure out what's wrong

Comment: Thanks your code is great. I tried it in my own application and I have a problem. Do you know why sometimes it loads the same image? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi! Well I don't know how you handle image loading exactly, but generally speaking: in my code you pass the image resID `(R.drawable.....)` to the `AsyncTask`. It will load the image that you requested by passing the corresponding resID.

Comment: I am using that ` int imageId = context.getResources().getIdentifier(currentStore.getImageName(), "drawable", context.getPackageName());` to get the id and then i pass it to your `AsyncImageSetter` as a variable.

Comment: well I could guess that you're sometimes passing the same resid

Comment: you should write a blog about it. it will help community alot. good answer though i haven't tried this but i will surely give it a shot... :)

Comment: @kiturk3 please note that this post dates back to 2013. As of now I strongly recommend to use the [RecyclerView](https://stackoverflow.com/documentation/recyclerview/5426/getting-started-with-recyclerview#t=201706270721598122486) instead of a `ListView`

Answer (score 1):

Use the listview scroll state to set the images accordingly.

1. When listview is flinged, don't set images right at the same time, once the state is idle, use your code to set the images.
   In this way it will avoid memory allocation for thos views which are not visible.If you try to set images when list view is scrolled, it can cause out of memory error.
2. Also, make sure that your drawable is having good size to fit in view. Getting images from drawable have always been fast, main concern here will be of memory usage.
3. Also create an array of drawables to set as your list item, so while setting the adapter you already have a hand full of drawables to be used for list item and do not populate list view with drawables based on condition

Comment: hi! Thanks for your contribution. 1). The implementation of my "cancel()" method ensures the image is only set when needed. 2). The images are being scaled to an appropriate size. 3). the getImage() method of my Weapon class returns the image ID which is taken from a such array