# How to improve performance on Android ListView

Tags: android, performance, listview, android-fragments, android-listview

My ListView is loading very slow. I have multiple tabs in my app and every time I switch to my ListView Tab it takes a very long time (~1-1.5 seconds).

my `getView()`method from the adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    final ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = LayoutInflater.from(ctx).inflate(R.layout.gallery_list_item, parent, false);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.image = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.text = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.text);
        holder.date = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.date);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    bindItems(position, holder);
    ImageLoader.getInstance().displayImage(Uri.fromFile(new File(documents.get(position).getPath())).toString(), holder.image, options, animateFirstListener);
    return convertView;
}

@Background
void bindItems(final int position, final ViewHolder holder) {
    holder.date.setTypeface(MainApplication.OpenSans(ctx));
    holder.text.setTypeface(MainApplication.OpenSansBold(ctx));

    SimpleDateFormat date = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
    SimpleDateFormat time = new SimpleDateFormat("hh:mm:ss");
    holder.date.setText(date.format(documents.get(position).getCreateDate()) + "  " + time.format(documents.get(position).getCreateDate()));

    holder.text.setText(documents.get(position).getDocument());
}
```

part of my `gallery_list_layout.xml`(displays apart from the list some buttons and a spinner which aren't relevant to my problem):

```
 <ListView
    android:id="@+id/mylist"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</ListView>
```

and my `gallery_list_item.xml` (for one list item):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/gallery_list"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="blocksDescendants" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_height"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:contentDescription="@string/app_name"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/date"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/chkbox"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

I left out some styling attributes to make it more readable.

**What I've done so far:**

- use Universal Image Loader, but the problem isn't the image loading (performance is about the same)
- use `match_parent`on `layout_height` and `layout_width` to only load the necessary data (this improves my performance A LOT, but still not enough)
- avoid any database querys in my Adapter `getView()` method
- bind the data in a background task

Does anyone see a mistake I made? What could I be doing wrong?

Comment: what kind of adapter is that? Array or Cursor?

Comment: array; my adapter extends `BaseAdapter`

Comment: that's probably why. How big is your data? how many documents?

Comment: the initial loading is only 6 items (space on the device), and even that takes long. In my list are ~30-50 items. How would I change it to Cursor?

Comment: you might want to perform some work in the background, you can check my related post where I described how I've solved performance issues in the `ListView` where I load some quite large images http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19469073/how-do-you-efficiently-load-bitmaps-from-drawable-folder-into-a-listview/19469076#19469076

Comment: you can use TimingLogger to time your various operations, see where is the time lost. Possibly the loading of the 30-50 items from the database (i assume) can be long, though that does not seem a very big number.

Comment: the typeface part seems a stronger lead to me.

Comment: I forgot to mention, I did test the time for various operations, non of them are really slow. Since I only load 6 items (and these items aren't loaded from the db in the adapter), I dont think it's a problem either

Comment: thank you for all the help everyone. I found a bug (some unnecessary call of an init method from another tab was the main problem, but changing typeface, TextViews etc the way you suggested helped me to improve the list as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all subclass the TextView and set the typeface there in constructor. It is not necessary to set the typeface every time new item comes in. You can also cache DateFormatters and LayoutInflater. Memory allocations are quite slow.

If you got RelativeLayout for positioning why do you nest the LinearLayout ? It is a little bit odd

Comment: thanks for the tipp with TextView. I did it, but the typeface unfortunately isn't the problem. The LinearLayout is still there because I didn't find time to fix it yet. I know it's a bit odd, but it shouldn't cause any problems, right?

Comment: It should not, try also cache the formatters. You can try to measure time of subsequent method calls - this will give you a trail what is a problem. You can check (by commenting out) if the line with ImageLoader is not a problem

Comment: my problem is fixed now. The main reason was an unnecessary call of an init method, but your fixes helped me to improve the list

Answer (score 0):

Place setTypeface in getview method in statement of  if(view==null)

Comment: true. creating a typeface can be heavy.

Comment: when I reload my list only the first 6 items are created (therefore setTypeface gets called as often as before). So putting it the setTypeface in view==null is of course a good tipp, thanks btw!, but it didnt help with the performance

Comment: You place setTypeface in bind method and it run  for all of items of listview no only for 6 itrms

Comment: I'll change the setTypeface, but it doesn't slow down the application (for testing I just removed it and it takes as much time as before)

Comment: It can cause for ImageLoader

Answer (score 0):

This `MainApplication.OpenSans(ctx)` probably create a full-fledged complete instance of typeface. It can be a rather lengthy operation.

I recommend you create it once when the app start, and use that reference ever after. (same goes for the other typeface, goes without saying)