# Adapter in Android Fragment

Tags: android, gridview, android-fragments, android-adapter

I'm new to Android and I'm trying to create a GridView inside a Fragment. But the line

```
addressGrid.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));
```

keeps giving me an error. In my code:

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
        Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_name, container, false);

    addressGrid = (GridView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.gridView1);
    addressGrid.setAdapter(new Adapter(this));

    return rootView;
}
```

I've tried to replace the (newAdapter(this)); with

```
(new Adapter(getActivity()));
```

and

```
(new Adapter(getContext()));
```

which are referenced on the Android Developer site but neither seem to work. I'm really hoping someone can help me figure out why I am getting this error and  how to fix it. Thank you in advance!

Comment: let me see your Adapter class

Comment: I figured out a different way of tackling the problem with a ListView. Thanks for your help though!

Answer (score 0):

Adapter is an interface, you re trying to instantiate an interface(which is not possible in Java), you should create a class that implementes Adapter and write your code or use one of the already provided classes like SimpleArrayAdapter, CursorAdapter, etc. My recommendation would be, create a class that extends from BaseAdapter if you want a specific layout in your views and some unique functionality for it.

You can look at this question for a better understanding on how to implement your own adapter.
[How to customize listview using baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter)

Hope it Helps!

Regards!