# How to build custom ListView in which each row has rectangles and circles

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-canvas, actionlistener

I have a class DrawView.java which draw a rectangle and I want to make a ListView of rectangle. I tried to draw the rectangle in getView() method of List adapter but I failed.

Can anyone help me in this issue?

My class which draw the rectangle is:

```
    public class DrawView extends View {
    Paint paint = new Paint();

    public DrawView(Context context) {
        super(context);            
    }

    @Override
    public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        paint.setColor(Color.BLACK);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(3);
        canvas.drawRect(30, 30, 180, 180, paint);
        paint.setStrokeWidth(0);
        paint.setColor(Color.CYAN);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 60, 177, 177, paint );
        paint.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
        canvas.drawRect(33, 33, 177, 60, paint );

    }

}
```

and my getView() method of custom adapter is:

```
               public View getView(final int position,  View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {

        convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.news_list_item,null);
        DrawView rl = (DrawView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.drawview);
        DrawView draw = new DrawView(c);
        rl=draw;
        return convertView;
}
```

My XML file is news_list_item:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="60dp"
    android:id="@+id/mainLayout"
     >

     <com.example.horizontalscrollview.DrawView
        android:id="@+id/drawview"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >
      </com.example.horizontalscrollview.DrawView>



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I think you need to define a layout for item. This layout will contain your DrawView, and you will inflate layout in your getView method

Comment: @LiemVo I updated  my getView() function but still getting nothing on my screen. Can you help me out

Comment: Please try this tutorial how to customer base adapter for your list view http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter

Comment: They are defining their custom layout in xml file and I am defining dynamically. SO I think there is no need to inflate. Here 'c' is my Context object from MainActivity. 
Even now I am not figuring out my mistake

Comment: I am not getting any rectangles on my screen and my application is crashing

Comment: Can you show me your crash message

Comment: I updated my getView() and xml file. The application is crashing by inflateException

Comment: Please post crash message

Comment: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class com.krish.horizontalscrollview.DrawView
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:596)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:687)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
at com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CustomListAdapter.getView(CustomListAdapter.

Comment: (CustomListAdapter.java:109)
 at com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview.fillViewWithAdapter(CenterLockHorizontalScrollview.java:49)
at com.krish.horizontalscrollview.CenterLockHorizontalScrollview.setAdapter(CenterLockHorizontalScrollview.java:28)
0at com.krish.horizontalscrollview.HorizontalScrollViewActivity.onCreate(HorizontalScrollViewActivity.java:68)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5158)
0 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:21

Comment: There's something wrong with your inflation clearly. Can you post the part of the LogCat that starts with 'Caused By: ', also I think you need only initialize convertView if it is null. Once that is done, call `convertView.invalidate()`

Comment: 04-10 13:42:59.276: E/AndroidRuntime(26265): Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: <init> [class android.content.Context, interface android.util.AttributeSet]
04-10 13:42:59.276: E/AndroidRuntime(26265):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructorOrMethod(Class.java:460)
04-10 13:42:59.276: E/AndroidRuntime(26265):  at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:431)
04-10 13:42:59.276: E/AndroidRuntime(26265):  at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:561)

Comment: Do you make sure DrawView is properly?

Comment: Ya, when I am calling the DrawView from MainActivity, it is displaying the rectangle

Comment: In class DrawView, onDraw() function takes the top left and bottom right coordinates of rectangle to draw it. But in listView the points where rectangles is to draw are changing. So is there any problem in this?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a list adapter by extending BaseAdapter. Your getView method is not properly using the convertView parameter. I recommend you watch [The World of ListView](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCkQtwIwAA&url=http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70&ei=GltFU6-uIM3YyAGr14GICg&usg=AFQjCNGAklAgezvQNN0PVmomzRjd7ci2uQ&sig2=Wlxfv2oy5r9Yy76Y43cwfw), which covers proper use of ListView.

**UPDATE**

1. Do not inflate a layout every time; only do so when convertView is `null`. The whole point of ListView is to recycle its views when they scroll off screen.
2. I see no reason for you to create a new instance of DrawView in `getView()`. It should be in the XML layout you are inflating.
3. The statement `r1=draw;` will not change the layout of the row in any way. All you've done is change the reference `r1` to point to a different View object (the new DrawView), but that view is not actually attached to the layout in any way. If you want to add it to the layout, you need to call `addView()` on some other view which you intend to be the container for the new DrawView.

If you haven't done so yet, please watch The World of ListView (link above) and follow the coding patterns presented.

Comment: I updated my getView() function of my custom adapter. Can you help me out, I am still getting nothing on my screen.