# ArrayAdapter mapping multiple arrays to Textviews

Tags: android, arrays, listview, android-arrayadapter

I am trying to use an `ArrayAdapter` with multiple arrays. This i a bit hard to explain for me.
What i have are a few `Arrays` which should be written in one `TextView` each in my `ListView`.
like -> `Array1` contains all the dates for `tv1`, `Array2` all the titles for `tv2` and so on.

```
ArrayAdapter<String> adapter =
                        new ArrayAdapter<String>(getActivity(),
                                R.layout.listview_layout, R.id.lv_date,
                                dates);
```

so, making an array for all the `TextViews` shouldn't be that hard, but how could I set whole 'arrays' to the `TextViews`?

Comment: I was able to solve my problem by following this accepted answer:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a rule, it is not recommended to build your data in this way. Instead of maintaining 2 `String` arrays, trying making a single array of a custom class that you build. This class could be very simple and only have 2 public members (`String s1, String s2`). Then `tv1` could pick up the data from `s1`, and `tv2` could pick up the data from `s2`.

Example:

```
public class MyData
{
    public String s1;
    public String s2;
}

// In the class with your adapter:
ArrayAdapter<MyData> adapter = //...
```

It's usually better to extend ArrayAdapter. This allows you to have full control of how you build the listview's item's data. There's plenty of reading material on that on the internet.

Comment: could you explain this a little further? I don't quite get it.

Comment: I'm sorry but i still don't get it. How exactly does this work? I'm really stuck here... Any Sites I can read more about this?

Comment: ListViews are not the simplest components to use for someone who is new to the topic. Here's a good tutorial you should go over: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidListView/article.html

Comment: I was able to solve it by following this accepted answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter
Thank you for your help. ListView is really complicated to understand for me... jeez

Answer (score 0):

Try to make the Custom ListView extends the ArrayAdapter or Base Adapter Class
Then You can pass the Multiple parameter and can be easily manageable.
here is the Example of Custom ListView.

[How to customize listview using baseadapter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter)