# How Create a ListView

Tags: android

My java Code is:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    String[] name;
    String[] family;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        name=new String[]{"aaa","bbb","ccc","ddd","fff"};
        family=new String[]{"Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi","Ahamadi"};

        ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);

        MyAdapter adapter=new MyAdapter(getApplicationContext());

        list.setAdapter(adapter);
    }//end method OnCreate

    private class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter

    {
        LayoutInflater MyInflater;
        public MyAdapter(Context context)
        {
            MyInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        }




        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return name.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        @SuppressLint("InflateParams")
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

            ViewHolder X=new ViewHolder();

            if(convertView==null)
            {
                convertView=MyInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item,null);

                X.Name=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_name);
                X.Family=(TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Text_family);

                convertView.setTag(X);
            }

            else{

                X=(ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }


            X.Name.setText(name[position]);
            X.Family.setText(family[position]);


            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return convertView;
        }


        //-class Holder
        public class ViewHolder
        {

            TextView Name;
            TextView Family;
        }
    }
}
```

and create a listView in Xml. While the programme runs, it shows the massage: "Applecation is stopped".

Comment: See what message appears at your LogCat and post it in your question

Comment: Post your log and/or activity_main.xml files.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter
refer this

Comment: Do you have a `ListView` with the reference id of "list_view" in your xml file? or rather a layout with the reference id of "list_item" in another xml file?

Comment: Maybe you should try to use to use `this` instead of `getApplicationContext()`

Comment: post your list_item.xml , I guess there might be some id mismatch issue.

Answer (score 0):

I see your code is correct, but probably you don´t have the elements inside your layout files:

for example your ListView:

```
 ListView list=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_View);
```

must be inside the `activity_main.xml` (example):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<ListView 
    android:id="@+id/list_View"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" /> 

</RelativeLayout>
```

and your `list_item.xml` must contain the TextView´s `Text_name` and `Text_family`  (example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"    
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>
         <TextView
            android:id="@+id/Text_family"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

**try using my .xml files, and please try to post the messages displayed in LogCat everytime you ask for a problem here in `stackoveflow.com`** =)

Answer (score 0):

change this:

```
public MyAdapter(Context context){
     MyInflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
}
```

by this :

```
public MyAdapter(Context context) {
    MyInflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
}
```

In your `Activity`, `onCreate`()

```
MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getBaseContext());
list.setAdapter(adapter);
```