# Maintaining List item state when List item property changed in its DetailsActivity?

Tags: android, listview, state, notifydatasetchanged

I have a listitem which has like option
if the user clicks the list item it details activity opens
if user clicks like option in details activity i want my listitem like state to be changed when used presses back button.
how to do it in easy way?

Comment: I think the easiest method would be to update the list in onResume by calling notifyDataSetChanged.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a boolean for each item to save this condition, and If you are using a custom adapter for the listitems, then you can check in the getView method this value and change the state of the option.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter) you have an example about the BaseAdapter and a custom implementation.