# How to add my own custom item id in a ListView

Tags: java, android

How to create a custom listview populated with data from a webservice, the data contains item with an ID, and a NAME. the NAME should be visible in the listView but when a user clicks on the item, i want to get the ID. i.e the ID from the server and not the ListView item id.

All i want is to be able to add my own item "properties" that i can get when the user clicks on an item

Comment: please post what you've tried so far.

Comment: You should override `getItemId` method in your `ListView` `Adapter`.

Comment: 1. Override `onItemClick`.
2. Get the object from the position,
3. Check the server for the id.

Comment: what about using model class for generating listitem. would be a good choice in this scenario

Comment: @KaranMer how exactly do i create such a class, do u have any guides i can follow

Comment: http://androidexample.com/How_To_Create_A_Custom_Listview_-_Android_Example/index.php?view=article_discription&aid=67&aaid=92

Comment: http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial/binding-android-listview-with-custom-objects-using-arrayadapter

Comment: @KaranMer now that was super helpful, exactly wat i needed, thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter check the answer by T_D

Answer (score 1):

Create a set-get class like:

```
private class NameDetails{
    private final String id;
    private final String name;

    public NameDetails(String id, String name){
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getid() {
        return id;
    }

    public String getname() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

Create a list containing the name and ids like:

```
List<NameDetails> namedetailssetget ;
namedetailssetget = new ArrayList<NameDetails>();
```

Now whenever you are getting name and ids,add them to the list like:

```
namedetailssetget.add(new NameDetails(id,name));
```

In this way you can add all your data to the list.

**To retrieve:**

Within the **onItemclickListner of listview** write:

```
if(namedetailssetget.size()>0){
    NameDetails item = namedetailssetget.get(position);
    String id=item.getid();
    String name=item.getname();
}
```

**N.B.** The above **position** is the position of the item of the listview clicked.