# How I can change the style of built-in-list-item layout in Android Studio

Tags: android, list, android-studio

I'm using one from the built-in list item layout in my app.

I want to change the style of this list like text color or size of text .

I'm using simple_list_item_1 from these items .

Can you help me how I can do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
You should make a custom Layout and inflate it in getView() method of Adapter.


 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
        View row;
        row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.custom, parent, false);
        TextView title, detail;
        ImageView i1;
        title = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.title);
        detail = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.detail);
        i1=(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.img);
        title.setText(Title[position]);
        detail.setText(Detail[position]);
        i1.setImageResource(imge[position]);

        return (row);
    }
```

you can look into this thing more on [Custom Listview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter)

and from my personal opinion you can use RecyclerView for better Customisation.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean in the Android Studio preview?

If so, `tools:listitem="@layout/list-item-layout"` is your friend.

Answer (score -1):

Create your own **layout** and place it in your **app layout directory** and refer that in your code instead of **simple_list_item_1**

**Example here**

```
R.layout.<yourLayoutName>
```

**instead of**

```
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1
```

And customize the layout as you like it!!

Comment: so I can't  customize the built-in list item , this is my question !

Comment: you can't ...because its builtin, but you can copy and place it elsewhere and manipulate it to meet your requirements