# Best practice for storing final List data

Tags: android, constants, android-adapter

i have the custom `ListView`, each item contains two icons, text, description, ect. it's static data, but i have several lists to display.

At that moment i save all this in final `ArrayList`s, like this:

```
    public static final int ACTION_MAIN = 1;
    public static final int ACTION_LEFT = 2;
    private static final List<ModelMenu> list = new ArrayList<ModelMenu>(){{
    add(new ModelMenu(ACTION_MAIN , R.drawable.icon_main, R.drawable.image_main, R.string.main, R.string.main_description, false));
    add(new ModelMenu(ACTION_LEFT , R.drawable.icon_left, R.drawable.image_left, R.string.left, R.string.left_description, false));
  }};
```

than pass `List` to adapter. in this case i use constants `ACTION_MAIN, ACTION_LEFT`, ect. to set it up like view id, and use it to understand which item were clicked in `OnItemClickListener` by `view.getId()`

is it ok? or is better to use for ex. XML [like done here](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text/)

**update 0:** found [one more](https://developer.android.com/samples/MediaRouter/res/values/arrays.html) option, but in this case we need to keep order for all resources...

or any other option is preferable?

**update 1:**
found another way to save actions:

```
<resources>
  <item type="id" name="menu_home"/>
  <item type="id" name="menu_login"/>
</resources>
```

Comment: If i where you I would go for Json data with Gson or Jackson. This way you can use a traditional Pojo and construct a cleaner data model

Comment: @An-droid, is my understanding correct: save file in assets in json format, then gets from assets and parse via Gson?

Comment: Yes that is a way of doing it

Comment: @An-droid, got it, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not modify the value of a variable when the modifier is `final`.

Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16335923/5429330), it is an example for populate a `ListView` using a custom adapter and extendig of `BaseAdapter`.

Hope this help.

Comment: thanks, i don't want to change it. it's items set, like menu, but menu not allows to store custom extensions. so, the question it: where i need to store item settings (links to resources\images\texts\ext)