# Custom adapter notifyDataSetChanged replaces old data

Tags: android

I'm trying to use a customAdapter to populate a listView and for some reason, when I add new data dynamically, the old data is replaced by new data and the new data added is completely out of order. Here is my custom adapter:

```
public class logAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    private ArrayList<String> kindArray = new ArrayList<String> (), logArray= new ArrayList<String> (), timeArray= new ArrayList<String> ();
    private ArrayList<Integer> viewKind= new ArrayList<Integer> ();
    private LayoutInflater inflater;

    public logAdapter(Context context) {
        inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return kindArray.size();
    }

    public void updateData(String kind, String log, String  time, Integer view) {
        this.kindArray.add(kind);
        this.logArray.add(log);
        this.viewKind.add(view);
        this.timeArray.add(time);
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View currentView = convertView;

        if (this.viewKind.get(position) == 0)
        {
            if (currentView == null) {
                currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_first, parent, false);
                TextView tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.addr);
                tView.setText(this.logArray.get(position));
                TextView timeView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                timeView.setText(this.timeArray.get(position));
            }



        }else if(this.viewKind.get(position) == 1){
            if (currentView == null) {
                currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_middle, parent, false);
                TextView tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.logMessage);
                tView.setText(this.logArray.get(position));
                TextView titleView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.kindText);
                titleView.setText(this.kindArray.get(position));
            }

        }else if(this.viewKind.get(position) == 2){
            if (currentView == null) {
                currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list, parent, false);
                TextView tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.logMessage);
                tView.setText(this.logArray.get(position));
                TextView titleView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.kindText);
                titleView.setText(this.kindArray.get(position));
                TextView timeView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                timeView.setText(this.timeArray.get(position));
            }

        }else if (this.viewKind.get(position) == 3)
        {
            if (currentView == null) {
                currentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.log_list_last, parent, false);
                TextView tView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.addr);
                tView.setText(this.logArray.get(position));
                TextView timeView = (TextView)currentView.findViewById(R.id.timeText);
                timeView.setText(this.timeArray.get(position));
            }

        }

        return currentView;
    }
}
```

I'm adding new data as with the following code

```
public void addLog(String date, String kind, Integer view, String log)
    {
        getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
            public void run() {
                adapter.updateData(kind, log, date, view);
                //simpleList.smoothScrollToPosition(logArray.size());
            }  });
    }
```

I don't understand why new data is added out of order and why old data is replaced in the listView.

Thanks for your help

Comment: When You add data from Activity first time you use `list.add("")` , But when you add more items, You can use other list and add  with this method  `addAll()` with the previous list. pretty  simple

Comment: Use a `POJO` class for data . And Follow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333754/how-to-customize-listview-using-baseadapter. Its hard to understand the uses of `viewKind`. Consider Using `RecyclerView` for multiple view types .

Comment: Hi but this does not explain why old data is replaced, and also not why data is out of order! I'm testing it with sequential data, and it goes well till I scroll for the first time

Comment: Do you know which is the best way for biding data?

Comment: Hi what @ADM said worked fine, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

iterated collections such as lists in Java are not in a guaranteed order , but it usually is the default OS file directory collating order.
You need to place in order the list as an array

**Use add() method initially only** to enter the element after list creation

Use toArray() to return an array of type "Object"

```
Object arraylist_object = namedarraylist_reference.toArray();
```

Use  T[] toArray(T[] a) to return an array from the ArrayList into its "particular object type"
**e.g. a string type**

```
String[] listedStrings = new String[namedarraylist_reference.size()];
namedarraylist_reference.toArray(listedStrings);
```

Use **set(int index, E element)** *to replace an element exactly where you want in the list*

```
namedarraylist_reference.set(3,"WHAT");
// or
namedarraylist_reference.set(7,listedStrings[4]);
```

call repaint() method on the GUI widget after.

**There may be a problem with using "public" methods upon "private" variables/objects too !**