# ViewAdapter is duplicating selected items in listview

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

So I have been searching all over for this solution, got some leads but never able to solve it. I read that it has something to do with the view being recycled but can't figure out how to stop that. Basically I have a listview and array adapter , in the listview there are check boxes and when I check an item and scroll down there is a random item selected again. The text is different but it seems that the items are checked in some sort of pattern.

Appreciate the help!

```
package com.example.myapplication;

private static final String TAG = viewContacts.class.getSimpleName();
ListView listView_Android_Contacts;
ListView viewContacts;
Cursor c;
CheckBox cb;
ArrayList<String> contacts;
ArrayList<String> listMessages;
LinearLayout linearMain;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_view_contacts);
    final ListView viewContacts = findViewById(R.id.contactsView);
    Dexter.withActivity(this)
            .withPermission(Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS)
            .withListener(new PermissionListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPermissionGranted(PermissionGrantedResponse response) {
                    get();
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionDenied(PermissionDeniedResponse response) {
                    // check for permanent denial of permission
                    if (response.isPermanentlyDenied()) {
                        // navigate user to app settings
                    }
                }

                @Override
                public void onPermissionRationaleShouldBeShown(PermissionRequest permission, PermissionToken token) {
                    token.continuePermissionRequest();
                }
            }).check();
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(
            this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, contacts
    );
    viewContacts.setAdapter(adapter);
    viewContacts.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            CheckedTextView checkedTextView = ((CheckedTextView)view);
            checkedTextView.setChecked(!checkedTextView.isChecked());
        }
    });
}

public void get(){

    c = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI, null, null, null, ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME );
    contacts = new ArrayList<>();
    while(c.moveToNext()){
        String contactName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.DISPLAY_NAME));
        String phoneNumber = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
        contacts.add( contactName + "\n" + phoneNumber);

        Log.d(TAG, "show contacts:");
    }
    c.close();
}
```

Comment: To solve this you have to create you own Custom adapter.

Comment: Is this my only option? Is there not anything else I can do to modify the existing code to get it working? Thanks - Jean.

Comment: I don't think bcoz you have to do some modification in `Bindview` method.

Comment: How would I go about creating my own custom-adapter by adapting my current code?

Comment: refer this example https://stackoverflow.com/a/20676526/8663811 ` custom-adapter` but it will not solve problem. Implement that adapter and your code here.Then i can help you.

Comment: I read on that thread that a listview with custom adapter is deprecated and I should use Recyclerview, is this true?

Comment: yes you can .ListView and RecyclerView have two different kind of adapter.

Comment: Hi frankenstein, just solved my issue, had absolutely nothing to do with the adapter, but rather commented out the code inside onitemclick that was the problem